# WordPress Advanced Custom Fields: Only pull attachments from custom field, not entire post

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using 2 custom fields... left_column & right_column which are WYSIWYG..so can add imagery... I want to runa check that "IF theres imagery, then add the class 'image_box'...

The thing is, I can get to identify images...but applying the logic to both columns...pulls in 2 sets of the images...regardless of what column (left or right) they were added to.

My code:

```
if(get_sub_field('extra_left_column')){
            if(get_sub_field('extra_left_column', $attachemnt['ID'])) {
                $extra_column_right.= '<div class="col6 right_column image_box">'.wpautop(apply_filters('the_content',get_sub_field('extra_right_column'))).'</div>';
            } else {
                $extra_column_right.= '<div class="col6 right_column">'.wpautop(apply_filters('the_content',get_sub_field('extra_right_column'))).'</div>';
            }
        }

        if(get_sub_field('extra_right_column')){

            if(get_sub_field('extra_right_column', $attachemnt['ID'])) {
                $extra_column_right.= '<div class="col6 margin_left right_column image_box">'.wpautop(apply_filters('the_content',get_sub_field('extra_right_column'))).'</div>';
            } else {
                $extra_column_right.= '<div class="col6 margin_left right_column">'.wpautop(apply_filters('the_content',get_sub_field('extra_right_column'))).'</div>';
            }
        }
```

I thought my code would be 'column specific' but it's not....if I add images only to my 'Righ tColumn' fileds within a post...it also pulls the same imagery into the 'left column' on the live site... so I've got duplicates... not good.

Answer (score 1):

First of all dump the values of both the subfields to see what data is being returned. If its just an empty field then, you can check for !empty() or !== ''.

If you are using v3.3.4 or later you can alos use a function called **has_sub_field**, to check if the field was set.